# How to upload files (pdf & doc) and display/read it in the view page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am a student and started to use ASP.NET Core MVC in creating a web-application for my project in school. My project has a feature of uploading pdf and doc files in the system and be able to display the uploaded files in the view page. I am really stuck on this part and my project must be out very soon. Please help me to solve this problem.

I've tried the existing code that I provided below and somehow successfully solve the uploading aspect. My problem is when I clicked the uploaded file in the index page, these error comes up:

This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44333/Users/GetPdf?fileName=sample.pdf
HTTP ERROR 404

It seems that I'm unable to read the uploaded file.

This is my Controller:

```
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using FileUpload.Models;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using System.IO;

    namespace FileUpload.Controllers
    {
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    private readonly FileUploadContext _context;
    private IHostingEnvironment _env;

    public HomeController(FileUploadContext context, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _context = context;
        _env = env;
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.User.ToListAsync());
    }
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(IFormFile file, User users)
    {
        var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "file", fileName);
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
            users.FileName = fileName;
        }
        _context.User.Add(users);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetPdf(string fileName)
    {
        string filePath = "~/file/" + fileName;
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
        return File(filePath, "application/pdf");
    }
}
}
```

This is my Model class:

```
namespace FileUpload.Models
{
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
}
```

This is my FileUploadContext

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace FileUpload.Models
{
public class FileUploadContext : DbContext
{
    public FileUploadContext(DbContextOptions<FileUploadContext> options) 
: base(options) { }
    public DbSet<FileUpload.Models.User> User { get; set; }
}
}
```

This is my Create.cshtml:

```
@model User

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"> 
</div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FileName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="FileName" type="file" name="file" id="file" 
 class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="FileName" class="text-danger"> 
</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<FileUpload.Models.User>
<p>
<a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FileName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>@Html.ActionLink(item.FileName, "GetPdf", "Users", new 
{ fileName = item.FileName }, null)</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route- 
 id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

I just want the users to open or read the file that are uploaded in the system. Please help me to solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with that error message. A 404 response means not found. So the route you're calling isn't registered with your application and then it responds with that 404.

I'm assuming that in `startup.cs` you haven't done any route configuration besides the default route (that is scaffolded when you generate a new project). So with this default route, the name of the controller type (without the Controller suffix) and the method name make up the route, such as `http://server[:port]/controller/action`.

Looking at your `Index.cshtml` view, you are generating the links for like this:

```cs
   <p>@Html.ActionLink(item.FileName, "GetPdf", "Users", new { fileName = item.FileName }, null)</p>
```

And there you are referencing the `Users` controller. Since I can see that your `Home` controller has a method called `GetPdf` I'm assuming that your error is based on calling the wrong controller. So change Users to Home and you should be good to go.